Sending the wrong value to the controller with Url.Action
I want to call an action in the controller in the view and I have to send a series of values ​​to the controller, but the action calls the controller but sends null values. please help me
enter image description here
Code in view:
var _getDocumentsUrl = '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("GetDocuments", "Document", new { Section = "0", Province = "1", County = "0", District = "0", area = "Province" }))';

Action in Controller:
public IActionResult GetDocuments(AreaVM area)
{///codes////}

Model:
public class AreaVM
{
    public string? Section {  get; set; }
    public string? Province {  get; set; }
    public string? County {  get; set; }
    public string? District {  get; set; }
}

Sending the values ​​of section = 0, Province = 1, County = 0, and District = 0 to the controller

What is the resulting URL that's produced in the view?

https://localhost:7266/Province/Document/GetDocuments?Section=0&Province=1&County=0&District=0

@hrmsystem is it work for you if you try ‘public IActionResult GetDocuments(string Section, string Province, string County, string District)
{
// Your code here
}’

So now we know what URL you got. But what URL did you want?

Please post the whole details codes about how you call this action and how you generate the url to let us reproduce the issue. Besides, inside the image you have shared, this is a post method, but it seems you want to use querystring to pass the data, why you don't do it by using the request body.

My problem was solved by changing area to model in GetDocuments action
public IActionResult GetDocuments(AreaVM model)


The area model isn't the MVC area parameter?

I changed its name as if area is a keyword. I don't understand what you mean

You have to specify from what part of query your object should be constructed. Url.Action pass parameters to uri, so probably you need that ([FromUri] added):
public IActionResult GetDocuments([FromUri]AreaVM area)

Read this for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-fromuri

But this is an MVC project, not a Web-API. I used exactly the same method for another part of the project, it works perfectly there, but it doesn't work here
